# Name of short story about earthlings trapped on foreign planet

Tags: story-identification, spaceship

There was a short story I read in 2004 about people from earth trapped on a foreign planet.  General ideas were as follows: people only lived for one week.. They grew quickly over the span of 7 days, people could only go out for 2 hours a day due to extreme temperatures, enemies and friendships were formed quickly...  The narrator is a man and ventures off to find the crashed spaceship (running the whole time to avoid the coming temperature drop). He is accompanied by a woman.. She is his love interest.  He successful saves the stranded civilization and everyone returns to earth.
My question is WHAT IS THE NAME OF THE STORY??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: Frost and Fire by Ray Bradbury - Book Cover]

Possibly ["**Frost and Fire**"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?64869) by Ray Bradbury.

Here are some excerpts from online reviews:

> When a ship, known as a seed, crash landed on the planet ten thousand
> days ago, it resigned the people to living in the cliffs, the only
> place they were safe from the sun where it was so hot it could burn
> them, and the nights were so cold they could freeze.

This mentions the central character and the short lifespan of his people...

> The plot follows Sim, the protagonist of this story, and his
> apparently short life on a planet where people are cursed by radiation
> to live only eight days.

And this talks about the brief window of time available each day:

> The only time of day they can leave is dawn and sunset for only an
> hour, where they can gather food, and enjoy the outside.

From other sources, here's a mention of the girl:

> Lyte is the girl he has chosen to marry. Together they try to discover
> the secret that might save them and their race from this unfortunate
> cycle.

<sup>*~ Edited from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frost_and_Fire_%28short_story%29) and [frostandfirerodriguez94](http://frostandfirerodriguez94.blogspot.com/2009/06/frost-and-fires-summary.html) and [theatermania](http://www.theatermania.com/los-angeles-theater/shows/frost-and-fire_137971/)*</sup>

Listen to an old [radio play](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AJ1P_bfbgfk) (alternate link [here](http://planetyesteryearotr.blogspot.com/2012/10/sci-fi-radio-episode-frost-and-fire-by.html)) adapted from the book. There's also the [graphic novel](http://www.comics.org/issue/39504/) pictured on top.

Comment: Wow, I hadn't seen those before :-) Looks like this is one of the ''popular'' stories!